# Ant -- Exclude my JUnit test classes from the Jar

Tags: java, ant

My Java project has two directories, `src/` and `tests/`, which contain the production code and the test code, respectively.

The package structure is mirrored in each directory — if `src/` has package a.b.c, then `tests/` also has an equivalent package a.b.c. The source files from both `src/` and `tests/` get compiled into the directory `bin/`. Because of the mirrored package structure, the test classes for package a.b.c get mingled in with the production classes for a.b.c.

I want an Ant target to build a jar, from the classes in `bin/`, but excluding all of the test files. I want to do this by mapping every filename `tests/a/b/c/D.java` `==>` `bin/a/b/c/D.class` and excluding the mapped filename from the jar.

Something like this:

```
<target ...>
    <!-- Build a jar that contains the class files which came from -->
    <!-- source files under src/, but not those which came from -->
    <!-- source files under tests/ -->
    <jar ...>
        <fileset dir="bin">
            <!-- EXCLUDE LOGIC -->
        </fileset>
    </jar>
</target>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to compile your `src` files to a `bin` directory in a `compile` target, and to compile the `test` files to a `testbin` directory in a `test-compile` target.  You set up the classpath for the `<javac>` in the `test-compile` target to include the `bin` directory and the JUnit and mocking jars.  You need to copy resources to the `bin` directory first so you can use them and override them with test versions.

Comment: Found an alternative how to do this (without a separate test directory) using ant exclude patterns here: http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-exclude-files-classes-compile-java-project-ant